# how to use traceview in eclipse for android development?

Tags: android

I want to use traceview in android in eclipse. I have a few questions:
1. Does my emulator phone need to have a sd card for traceview to work?
2. Is there anyway to start traceview directly from eclipse ide?

I did try to put sd card memory in my avd device but still i cannot find the folder marked sdcard.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38):

In Eclipse in the DDMS perspective you have to select your process in the devices view.
Then click on the Start Method Profiling icon (three arrows with a red dot).

Once you are done click the same button again (it now has a black stop sign to signal that tracing is activated) and the trace file is automatically pulled from the device/the emulator and the results are displayed.

Answer (score 4):

You can start Tracing with the eclipse integrated DDMS. After that you have to pull the created .trace file. Import that to your workspace and double click on it to open the view.

Myself didn't manage to get it to work because my whole eclipse crashed after that.

Comment: ?? you have written "I want to use traceview in android in eclipse". So i think you want to use traceview

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an sdcard if you specify an absolute path to Debug.startMethodTracing. Be aware, though that tracing can generate enormous files, so use it sparingly if you aren't going to use the sdcard. I don't think there's a way to start traceview directly from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

R10 says that traceview can now be started from eclipse ([see here](http://tools.android.com/recent/traceviewineclipse))

But I did not figured out how yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trace view directly from DDMS window on clicking profiling option and open trace view

[image]

[image]

Thanks