# eclipse pause how to get useful stack trace in my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Sometimes my app gets its self into a loop. in debug mode I can pause it of course but in the Debug window i get a useless stack trace, telling me its in DalvikVM somewhere.

Is there a way I can find out where it is in my app? like the pause in visual studio.

Right now I just have to guess where it might be and put break points in which seems like a waste of time.

Comment: i guess not. if anyone from eclipse development reads this, please add

Comment: To get a better estimate you can use traceview and create a trace to see in which method of yours the most time is spent and then set a breakpoint there.

Comment: interesting idea. i know nothing about this but did find some useful stuff to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850974/how-to-use-traceview-in-eclipse-for-android-development and http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html