# small lags when starting the next moveTo action

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

[UPDATE] i changed the order a bit so i call the `super.act(delta)` at the end of the method and it seems to help a bit! But not that sure about it yet.

I got a square system for my map. So its an 2D array and i i make one move the figure does move from one square to the next. While that it's not possible to "stop" the figure between 2 squares.
 When my characters made one move i check if the Touchpad is touched and if yes i start the next move. While that it seems to lag sometimes and i dont know why!? I really hope you may find the "lag". Here is how i calculate the next move inside the `act()`of my `Actor` Character:

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta); // so the actions work
    if (moveDone) {
        if (screen.gameHud.pad.isTouched()) {
            // check in which direction is the touchcontroller
            if (screen.gameHud.pad.getKnobPercentX() < 0
                    && Math.abs(screen.gameHud.pad.getKnobPercentY()) < Math
                            .abs(screen.gameHud.pad.getKnobPercentX())) {
                // checkt if the |x|>|y|
                if (checkNextMove(Status.LEFT)) {
                    this.status = Status.LEFT;
                    move(Status.LEFT);
                    this.screen.map.mapArray[(int) (this.mapPos.x)][(int) this.mapPos.y] = Config.EMPTYPOSITION;
                    this.screen.map.mapArray[(int) (this.mapPos.x - 1)][(int) this.mapPos.y] = Config.CHARSTATE;
                    this.mapPos.x--;
                    moveDone = false;
                }
            } else if //.... rest is the same just with other directions
else{ //if touchpad isnt touched!
    setIdle();
}
updateSprite(delta); //just change the textureRegion if its time for that
} //methode end
```

Okay so you need some more informations i am sure. Checkmoves like this:

```
case LEFT:
        if (this.mapPos.x - 1 >= 0)
            if (this.screen.map.mapArray[(int) (this.mapPos.x - 1)][(int) this.mapPos.y] == Config.EMPTYPOSITION)
                return true;
        break; //same for all other just direction changin
```

And the last you need to know is the `move(_)` i guess. It does add an moveTo Action to my figures.

```
public void move(Status direction) {
    switch (direction) {
    case LEFT:
        this.addAction(Actions.sequence(
                Actions.moveTo((getX() - Config.BLOCK_SIZE), getY(), speed),
                moveDoneAction));
        break;
```

moveDoneAction is a simple `RunnableAction` that set the `boolean moveDone` to true if its done moving.
i really hope you can help. If you need some more informations please let me know as comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better tools than StackOverflow for optimizing Android code.  Use a profiler and see what is actually happening.  Specifically, the traceview profiler: [how to use traceview in eclipse for android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850974/how-to-use-traceview-in-eclipse-for-android-development)  (If you're not using Eclipse, you can use traceview directly via the ADT.)

Comment: Thanks on that advice. But i really do not know how to use the trace. (MethodTracing) I made a trace but all i know now is that the move Methode is around 70% of the whole calculation time of one cycle.

Comment: i Optimized the move method so i do not create new instances of the Actions just change the one action and add it again. Does look way better in the trace.

Thanks on that

Comment: Yeah, creating objects in the render path can lead to hiccups and slowdown.  Use the DDMS memory allocation tracker to track those down and eliminate them.

Comment: Actually i guess your tip did fix it really good. thanks on that Going to take it as correct answer. Thanks for the selflerningtip so i could fix it myself.